# bug in launch file vision_visp stack

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm debugging and trying to run a launch file in **vision_visp** stack which is **tutorial.launch**

```
  <node pkg="visp_tracker" type="client" name="tracker_mbt_client">
    <param name="model_path" value="package://visp_tracker/models" />
    <param name="model_name" value="laas-box" />
```

in parameter "model_path" value is "package://something" -> **what's this syntax**?? I've replaced with the full path but still didn't work

I believe this is the problem, because from the output:

```
process[tf_localization-6]: started with pid [18717]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Failed to load the model /home/airlab/SONLE/stacks/vision_visp/visp_tracker/models/laas-box/laas-box.wrl
Do you use resource_retriever syntax?
I.e. replace /my/model/path by file:///my/model/path
```

I've already fixed one bug in this launch file

```
 <node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag" args="play --clock -l
  $(find visp_tracker)/bag/tutorial-static-box.bag"/>
```

where type="rosbag" is not correct, there's no rosbag executable in the package but "play" => changed to:

```
<node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbag_routine" args=" --clock -l
      $(find visp_tracker)/bag/tutorial-static-box.bag"/>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46298/bug-in-launch-file-vision_visp-stack/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So what exactly is your question?

Changing `package://` to a full path is always a bad idea. If you want roslaunch to put in the path to a package, use `$(find package)`. URIs of the form `package://` are normally resolved using [resource_retriever](http://ros.org/wiki/resource_retriever) inside the node.

If you have bug reports or patches, it's normally best to file a ticket at the package's bug tracker.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-19**:
"normally best to file a ticket at the package's bug tracker" -> thank you for this guide!

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-19**:
"package://something -> what's this syntax" -> I mean this question. Is this the correct syntax?? from where? resource_retriever?

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-19**:
I think I've just seen the syntax in resource_retriever page of ROS. Thank you!!

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-19**:
I've tried to change from      to

but still no work

**Comment by [adreno](https://answers.ros.org/users/4576/adreno/) on 2014-06-27**:
Hey, I am having the same problem...any solution for this ?